# How to transpose a matrix in python without zip

Tags: python

I was wondering how you could change the user input in python into a list, or better yet, a matrix, just as you would convert it to an integer by using int(input).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the zip() function? Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/2001600) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16179794/2001600)?

Comment: Jamylak has answered your question you need accept, [how to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> [[x[i] for x in L] for i in range(len(L[0]))]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

or

```
>>> zip(*L)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

or

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3))
>>> L
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> L.transpose()
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: it must be `range(len(L[0]))`

Comment: OP specified that he does not want to use zip.

Comment: @hd1 Yes I gave him the alternative but may as well put `zip` in there for other people who may view this question

Comment: @jamylak It's elegant + simple! You could have explain `list comprehension`.

Answer (score 4):

`array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]).T` will do what you want, if you're using [numpy](http://numpy.org).

Comment: I cannot find '.T', but found numpy.transpose http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

Answer (score 0):

list comprehensions should fit the bill quite nicely.  Here's the general function:

```
def transpose(the_array):
    return [[the_array[j][i] for j in range(0, len(the_array[i]))] for i in range(0, len(the_array))]
```